# How to include .pyx file in python package

Tags: python, cython

I used cython in my packages [pyirt](https://github.com/17zuoye/pyirt), but when I published it to the pypi, the .pyx file is not included in the tar.gz

I think it must has something to do with the setup file. However, I cannot find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may want to add a `MANIFEST.in` file to the top level of your project and add following line:

```
global-include *.pyx
global-include *.pxd
```

You can find valid commands for the `MANIFEST.in` file [`here`](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html#commands).

Comment: Also add pakcage_data and include_package_data clause in the setup.py. In any case, many thxs

Comment: @IoannisFilippidis, do you mean `*.pxd`? The Manifest you linked globally excludes `*.pyd` files.

Comment: Oops, good catch. I meant [`*.pxd` files](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/pxd_files.html). The `numpy` Manifest is [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/a38888c18cd2a20de0eb0578b3fa8660cda79582/MANIFEST.in#L12).

Comment: @IoannisFilippidis, thanks! I updated my answer and included your suggestion.