# `python setup.py sdist` with cython extension: .pyx' doesn't match any files

Tags: python, pip, cython, setuptools

I'm maintaining a python package which includes a cython-based c extention.
The source code is on github: https://github.com/vlkit/vlkit.

Here is my `setup.py`:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from distutils.core import Extension

try:
    import numpy
except ImportError:  # We do not have numpy installed
    os.system("pip install numpy")

try:
    from Cython.Build import cythonize
except ImportError:  # We do not have Cython installed
    os.system("pip install Cython")

import numpy
from Cython.Build import cythonize

__version__ = "0.1.0-b3"

exts = [Extension(name='vltools.nms.nms_ext',
                  sources=["vltools/nms/nms_ext.pyx"],
                  include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])
        ]

setup(name='vltools',
  version=__version__,
  description='vision and learning tools',
  url='https://github.com/vltools/vltools',
  author_email='a@b.c',
  license='MIT',
  packages=find_packages(),
  ext_modules=cythonize(exts),
  zip_safe=False,
  data_files=[("data", ["data/imagenet1000_clsidx_to_labels.txt"])]
)
```

When building locally with `python setup build && python setup.py install`, everything goes smoothly.

However, when I'm trying to create a **source distribution** with `python setup.py sdist` and then install from the generated `dist/vltools-0.1.0b3.tar.gz` it run into an error:

```
ValueError: 'vltools/nms/nms_ext.pyx' doesn't match any files
```

In my understanding, the one actually required for installation is `nms_ext.c` which is indeed inside the generated `dist/vltools-0.1.0b3.tar.gz`.

However, in my setup.py it's "nms_ext.pyx" in the sources:

```
exts = [Extension(name='vltools.nms.nms_ext',
                  sources=["vltools/nms/nms_ext.pyx"],
                  include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])
        ]
```

So what should I do when creating a source distribution with `python setup.py sdist`?

Comment: Works for me. Try to upgrade `pip`, `setuptool` and `Cython`.

Comment: Could you add which version of python, pip, etc. you're using? Could you also add which exact command you type when you run into the error? (I guess it's `pip3 install --user dist/vltools-0.1.0b3.tar.gz`, but it's better to confirm in the question)

Comment: Is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29227836/how-to-include-pyx-file-in-python-package any help?

Comment: By the way, the `try: import numpy except: os.system(pip install numpy)` is a bad idea. Just letting the error raise is fine. Because typically, if numpy is not found, it means you're not using the exe you thought you were using (e.g. if python2 is installed next to a python3).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found @hoefling's answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things to fix or improve in your setup script.

#### Declaring build and runtime dependencies

Instead of running `pip install {numpy,cython}` where a lot of things can go wrong, a proper way of declaring dependencies is to pass them to `setup()` in the `setup_requires`/`install_requires` args. Cython is required only at the build stage, but not when `vltools` is installed and imported - it will be added to `setup_requires`. `numpy` is required to both build and run the package, so it is included in both lists:

```
setup(
    ...,
    setup_requires=["cython", "numpy"],
    install_requires=["numpy"],
)
```

This has the advantage that Cython won't be installed. It will be downloaded, used for building and then removed.

You can (and should) extend the `install_requires` list with other packages `vltools` requires, for example `scipy`, `pillow` etc.

#### Deferring Cython and numpy imports

To ensure the package is installable on a system that has neither Cython nor `numpy` installed beforehand, we have to defer their imports. I won't go into much detail here; check out [Add numpy.get_include() argument to setuptools without preinstalled numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54117786/2650249) for more details. In the custom impl of the `build` command below, I defer both cythonizing and extending extension headers with `numpy` includes:

```
class build(build_orig):

    def finalize_options(self):
        super().finalize_options()
        __builtins__.__NUMPY_SETUP__ = False
        import numpy
        for extension in self.distribution.ext_modules:
            extension.include_dirs.append(numpy.get_include())
        from Cython.Build import cythonize
        self.distribution.ext_modules = cythonize(self.distribution.ext_modules,
                                                  language_level=3)
```

Register the custom command impl via `cmdclass`:

```
setup(
    ...,
    cmdclass={"build": build},
)
```

#### Packaging `nms.h`

Currently, the `nms.h` is not being added to your source dist, making the installation impossible. This is easily fixed by including it via e.g. `package_data`:

```
setup(
    ...,
    package_data={"vltools.nms": ["nms.h"]},
)
```

Now you also should add the parent dir of `nms.h` to `include_dirs`:

```
exts = [Extension(name='vltools.nms.nms_ext',
                  sources=["vltools/nms/_nms_ext.c", "vltools/nms/nms_ext.pyx"],
                  include_dirs=["vltools/nms"])]
```

#### Full setup script

```
import os
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools import Extension
from distutils.command.build import build as build_orig

__version__ = "0.1.0b3"

exts = [Extension(name='vltools.nms.nms_ext',
                  sources=["vltools/nms/_nms_ext.c", "vltools/nms/nms_ext.pyx"],
                  include_dirs=["vltools/nms"])]


class build(build_orig):

    def finalize_options(self):
        super().finalize_options()
        __builtins__.__NUMPY_SETUP__ = False
        import numpy
        for extension in self.distribution.ext_modules:
            extension.include_dirs.append(numpy.get_include())
        from Cython.Build import cythonize
        self.distribution.ext_modules = cythonize(self.distribution.ext_modules,
                                                  language_level=3)


setup(name='vltools',
    version=__version__,
    description='vision and learning tools',
    url='https://github.com/vltools/vltools',
    author_email='kz@kaizhao.net',
    license='MIT',
    packages=find_packages(),
    ext_modules=exts,
    setup_requires=["cython", "numpy"],
    install_requires=["numpy"],
    zip_safe=False,
    data_files=[("data", ["data/imagenet1000_clsidx_to_labels.txt"])],
    package_data={"vltools.nms": ["nms.h"]},
    cmdclass={"build": build},
)
```

---

P.S. [Two years have passed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49861124/2650249) and here we meet again ;-)

Comment: Wow, so amazing that you helped me again! I've updated!

Comment: @KaiZHAO if this answer really helped you, then why don't you accept it and mark it as solved? It will help others if you do so... More than 2 years passed and you still have the same issue.. I'm  confused...

Comment: @Cyborg I have marked it as solved. I just don't know there is such a functionality for stackoverlof to choose a specific answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

As [@hoefling suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60730258/4095689), I've updated my `setup.py`.

However, there is still an error when installing from `.tar.gz` file that it cannot find 'vltools/nms/nms_ext.pyx'.

**setup.py hoefling posted:**

```
import os
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools import Extension
from distutils.command.build import build as build_orig

__version__ = "0.1.0b3"

exts = [Extension(name='vltools.nms.nms_ext',
                  sources=["vltools/nms/_nms_ext.c", "vltools/nms/nms_ext.pyx"],
                  include_dirs=["vltools/nms"])]


class build(build_orig):

    def finalize_options(self):
        super().finalize_options()
        __builtins__.__NUMPY_SETUP__ = False
        import numpy
        for extension in self.distribution.ext_modules:
            extension.include_dirs.append(numpy.get_include())
        from Cython.Build import cythonize
        self.distribution.ext_modules = cythonize(self.distribution.ext_modules,
                                                  language_level=3)


setup(name='vltools',
    version=__version__,
    description='vision and learning tools',
    url='https://github.com/vltools/vltools',
    author_email='kz@kaizhao.net',
    license='MIT',
    packages=find_packages(),
    ext_modules=exts,
    setup_requires=["cython", "numpy"],
    install_requires=["numpy"],
    zip_safe=False,
    data_files=[("data", ["data/imagenet1000_clsidx_to_labels.txt"])],
    package_data={"vltools.nms": ["nms.h"]},
    cmdclass={"build": build},
)
```

When installing with `python setup.py sdist && cd dist && pip install vltools-0.1.0b3.tar.gz`, there is an error saying:

```
ValueError: 'vltools/nms/nms_ext.pyx' doesn't match any files
```

Becase the `pyx` file was not packed into tar.gz.

To have 'vltools/nms/nms_ext.pyx' in the tar.gz file, I add it into the `package_data` list:

```
package_data={"vltools.nms": ["nms.h", "nms_ext.pyx"]}
```

Finally, my full setup.py is:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools import Extension
from distutils.command.build import build as build_orig

__version__ = "0.1.0b3"

exts = [Extension(name='vltools.nms.nms_ext',
                  sources=["vltools/nms/_nms_ext.c", "vltools/nms/nms_ext.pyx"],
                  include_dirs=["vltools/nms"])]


class build(build_orig):

    def finalize_options(self):
        super().finalize_options()
        __builtins__.__NUMPY_SETUP__ = False
        import numpy
        for extension in self.distribution.ext_modules:
            extension.include_dirs.append(numpy.get_include())
        from Cython.Build import cythonize
        self.distribution.ext_modules = cythonize(self.distribution.ext_modules,
                                                  language_level=3)


setup(name='vltools',
    version=__version__,
    description='vision and learning tools',
    url='https://github.com/vltools/vltools',
    author_email='kz@kaizhao.net',
    license='MIT',
    packages=find_packages(),
    ext_modules=exts,
    setup_requires=["cython", "numpy"],
    install_requires=["numpy"],
    zip_safe=False,
    data_files=[("data", ["data/imagenet1000_clsidx_to_labels.txt"])],
    package_data={"vltools.nms": ["nms.h", "nms_ext.pyx"]},
    cmdclass={"build": build},
)
```

Comment: Interesting, as I have checked and the `nms_ext.pyx` is included in the sdist tar without having to add it explicitly. May it be a difference in the installed packages? This is what I have installed in the virtual environment: `Cython==0.29.15`, `numpy==1.18.2`, `pip==20.0.2`, `setuptools==45.2.0`, `wheel==0.34.2`. Other than that, no idea so far.